# App To Scan Hyperlinks|Content On A Web Page?

Tags: applications, hyperlinks, text-selection

The concept is same as scanning QR codes, but only hyperlinks and content. Is there such an app?

Sometimes i see long hyperlink on a web page that i would like to have copied to my smartphone.

Comment: FYI we prefer questions that are "how can I do X" questions, rather than "I need an app that does X" questions. While the answer to the first type may well be an app, the second is too narrow and smacks of a shopping recommendation. It is hoped that questions asked will be helpful to people facing the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Scanning a hyperlink on a page (visually, as QR code usually is) can be problematic.  After all, almost every link on the page you're reading does not present a full URL that can be used by the handset (e.g. [http://www.google.com](http://stackoverflow.com) doesn't bring you where it says that it does).  In light of this, the [Chrome to Phone extension](http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/) for the Chrome browser can send  a page to your phone where you can bookmark it.  In addition, you get several other nice features (send a highlighted number to your phone's dialer from the browser or launch Google Maps links on your phone from a browser link). Very handy.

If you aren't thrilled with Chrome, Firefox even has an [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/foxtophone/)

Comment: Chrome to Phone is nice, definitely +1

Answer (score 1):

#### [Google Goggles](http://www.google.com/mobile/goggles/#text)

You can basically scan text with it and it is copied to the device as raw text.

Comment: @slhck: But internet/mobile packet data is required.

Comment: Worth mentioning, yeah. But where's the sense in having an Android phone without data plan anyway? :)

Comment: @Xperia how do you use a hyperlink without a data connection?

Comment: @GAThrawn - I am sitting before a Computer. I saw a hyperlink which I want to copy to my mobile. There are two options. One is that open the same web page on mobile and copy the link. Second one is taking a picture. And Itsn't worth. Because we cannot copy the text from a Picture. Using Google Goggles we can read the text anywhere not only from Computer. This is what my understanding is.

Comment: Google Goggles does not copy raw text, it only takes pictures.

Comment: ... and converts text in that picture into raw text.